# when entering pip install numpy recieved syntax error

Tags: module, python-3.8, windows64

new to python and trying to learn some data science, Ive downloaded python 3.8.3 for windows64 two the few things I learned at  during the short free trial.
when trying to install numpy I received a syntax error, even though pip was imported and the path is shown.

```
>>> pip
<module 'pip' from 'C:\\Users\\owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site- 
packages\\pip\\__init__.py'>
>>> pip install numpy
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

typing python in windows command prompt just brings up the windows store on the python app, and typing pip doesn't find anything as well.

```
C:\Users\owner>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

in general, it seems that none of the commands that aren't `print()` or `help()` is working.
what did I do wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you add Python to System Environment PATH when you are installing python.

[image: Python Install]

If you didn't try this command to add it to your PATH

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"
```